# Root access via adb only, not any Android applications

Tags: nexus-4, root-access

I'm running a stock Android 4.2.2 on a Nexus 4 device. After following some instructions on how to root it, I managed to get a *partially* rooted phone. Now on `adb shell` I can do:

```
shell@android:/ $ su
shell@android:/ # whoami
whoami: unknown uid 0
```

With `adb shell` I can get access to `/data/data`, etc. No problem. And my SuperSU.apk automatically grants it super user permission. **However**, nothing else gets *super-user* permission, not even SuperSU itself. No notification/prompt ever comes. Even after setting SuperSU to default to allowing access after timeout.

## Any ideas on possible causes? Any suggestions?

Flashed this zip from (http://download.chainfire.eu/282/SuperSU/).

```
 4c3054dfecb6d21dc6a01d67c25588af CWM-SuperSU-v0.98.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

You must go in Settings -> Developer Options and there must be an option called "Root Access". Set it to `ADB + Apps`.

Comment: Unfortunately as I mentioned I am using stock Android not Cyanogenmod...